# how do I rebuild data frame based on columns identified in a numeric vector?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using R to complete some GA driven searches.

Returned from my GA script is the resulting chromosome, returned as a binary numeric of length 40.

An example is: `c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`.

I also have a corresponding data frame with 40 columns.

Using the data in the numeric vector, how do I efficiently build a (or re-build the) data frame so that it contains only those columns represented by the 1's in my numeric vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a sample data.frame and assigning your sample vector to x:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, 400, replace=T), ncol=40))
x <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I can subset:

```
df[ ,x==1]
```

or:

```
df[, as.logical(x)]
```

Comment: Perfect answer - thank you.  I was getting in a right mess with for-loops etc (too may years of VBA...)

Comment: @tfb glad to help.  You might want to take a look at    [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)  I find its a great learning tool to avoid some of these pitfalls.